# Outlook HTMLBody cid images links

Tags: html, email, outlook, email-attachments

I import messages from Outlook via MAPI (Python, win32com) and get HTMLBody for further saving and working with browser. In the case of embedded images, it gives `<img>` tags with links like

```
src=""cid:image00X.png@FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF""
```

Where `image00X.png` is the attached file and `F` are digits.

How should I edit/save files (HTML and attached images) to make it possible to view via browser?

Answer (score 0):

You need to process/change the message body removing the `cid` attribute and other artefacts around image names. When attachments/images are saved to the same folder the message body can be displayed correctly in the browser.

But I'd suggest processing the whole HTML markup created by Word (`HTMLBody`) and removing additional artefacts, not only the `cid` attribute. You can find various libraries on github that helps to do that.